# DeflateStream closes the input stream

Tags: c#, .net

Here is my C# method to write zlib-compressed data and some extra data to a stream:

```
  using (var compressor = new DeflateStream(compressStream, CompressionMode.Compress)) {
    compressor.Write(input, 0, input.Length);
    compressor.Close();
    compessStream.Write(extraData, 0, extraData.Length);
  }
```

When `compressor.Close()` is called, it automatically closes the input stream. As a result, I cannot write extra data to the stream.

If I close the compressor after writing my extra data, the order of data is no longer valid. My extra data gets written before the compressed data and not after as I intended to.

Why does `DeflateStream.Close()` close the input stream as well? Is there a way of getting around it short of writing a stream class that wraps the actual stream class and prevents the latter from closing? Regards.

Comment: `new DeflateStream(compressStream, CompressionMode.Compress, leaveOpen: true)`

Answer (score 2):

The DeflateStream close the underlying stream when closing/disposing because it designed this way:

```
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    try {
        this.PurgeBuffers(disposing);
    }
    finally {
        try {
            if (disposing && !this._leaveOpen && this._stream != null) {
                this._stream.Close();
            }
        }
        finally {
            this._stream = null;
            try {
                if (this.deflater != null)  {
                    this.deflater.Dispose();
                }
            }
            finally {
                this.deflater = null;
                base.Dispose(disposing);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By default, DeflateStream owns the underlying stream, so closing the stream also closes the underlying stream.

You can control this behavior by using the [specific constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bc2dbwea(v=vs.110).aspx) for the DeflateStream that allow you to leave the underlying stream open:

```
public DeflateStream(
    Stream stream,
    CompressionMode mode,
    bool leaveOpen
)
```